# Float form elements within list

Tags: css-float, html-lists, forms

I am trying to achieve the following effect, where here i'm using ( ) to represent a radio button:

```
Y    N
( )  ( )  1.  blah blah blah blah.
( )  ( )  2.  blah blah blah blah
              blah blah blah.
( )  ( )  3.  blah blah blah blah.
```

The following fiddle gives close to what I want on Safari & Chrome, 
but not Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/RKfrk/7. But on Firefox, 
the radio buttons do not float left. I haven't tried IE.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a negative margin in order to move the radio buttons to the left of the list numbers:

```
.floatingButtons {
     width: 4em;
     float:left;
     margin-left:-4em;
 }
 .clearFloat {
     clear:left;
 }
 li {
     margin-left:2em;
 }
```

here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mmertel/7mBkR/